# strace on two instances of java

Tags: java, execution, system-calls, strace

I want to trace the execution of a java process. 
For that I am using strace to analyse it.

I have written two basic programs.

Prog1 : Simple hello world

Prog2 : Prime number calculation with lots of Sysout's. By lots I really mean lots !!

I am taking strace using : strace java classfile

Both the program work correctly. However, when I compare their straces, their outputs were same i.e. the system calls and their order.

My queries are :

1. What can be reason behind this ?
2. What would be the correct way to strace a java program ?
3. The statements being printed are not part of the strace ... actually there is no write system call in the strace output ?

Comment: Does it have a report capabilities?

Comment: There are some sites with similar keywords 'strace' and 'java'. But they are not providing me with any useful information

Comment: @RomanC What do you mean by report capabilities ??

Comment: `strace` works at the hardware instruction level, and will not relate directly to the Java code.  `strace` is the wrong tool to examine Java unless you're trying to debug the JVM itself and not your java code.

Comment: Please add the option `-f` to the _strace_ call. Does it change anything?

Comment: @nosid Dude its working with -f option but i don't understand how ? I mean the strace output without -f option had two execve system calls but no fork system call.

Comment: @prathmesh.kallurkar: The name of the system call is _clone_, not _fork_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the program *strace* does not trace child processes. However, the Java VM creates early in the process a child process for the actual work. That's the reason, why the two different programs generate the same result when invoked with *strace*.

To also trace child processes, use the option `-f` to *strace*, i.e.:

```
strace -f java Hello
```

Comment: Dude its working with -f option but i don't understand how ? I mean the strace output without -f option had two execve system calls but no fork system call. Infact fork is not there in the new strace output also.